# SQL to get customer emails by attribute set of products bought

Tags: email, sql

@I would like to export a list of customer emails who have bought a product belonging to a specific attribute set.

Im unsure on where to gather the customer email informaiton from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1.
Get all products from that specific attribute set:

```
$attributeSetId = 5;//replace with your value
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id', $attributeSetid);
$productIds = $collection->getAllIds();
```

Step 2. get all order items for products above.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', array('in'=>$productIds));
$orderIds = array();
foreach ($collection as $item){
    $orderIds[] = $item->getOrderId();
}
```

Step 3. Get customer emails that placed the orders above.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>$orderIds));
$custoemrEmails = array();
foreach ($collection as $order){
    $customerEmails[] = $order->getCustomerEmail();
}
```

Step 4. Do your magic with `$customerEmails`.

I hope I didn't make any syntax errors. I wrote the code of the top of my head.
**[EDIT]**
Here is a direct sql. I'm not 100% sure of it but give it a try:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT(o.customer_email) 
FROM
    sales_flat_order o
    LEFT JOIN 
        sales_flat_order_item oi 
    ON 
        o.entity_id = oi.order_id
WHERE
  oi.product_id IN 
     (SELECT 
         entity_id 
      FROM 
          catalog_product_entity 
      WHERE 
          attribute_set_id = 5
      )
```

Replace `5` with your attribute set id.  And add table prefixes if you have any.

Comment: Thats brilliant. Is there a way to write this out as straight SQL. i am using a store manager and it has the facility to make custom reports via direct SQL queries on the DB.

Comment: @SiParker. See my update for the answer.

Comment: Hi I think i now have this right but im never getting an output.
If you could check the below am i correct where the attribute set i am looking for info from has an ID of 40

`Select Distinct (o.customer_email), oi.product_id
From mage_sales_flat_order o Left Join
  mage_sales_flat_order_item oi On o.entity_id = oi.order_id
Where oi.product_id In (Select mage_catalog_product_entity.entity_id
  From mage_catalog_product_entity
  Where mage_catalog_product_entity.attribute_set_id = 40)`

Comment: @SiParker.Seams right. Maybe you don't have any products that fit the condition. If I change 40 with one of my attribute set ids I get results.

Comment: Hi Yeah i do have plenty of products in attribute set 40.
Im just not sure why its not showing them. 
will persevere. Thanks very much for your input it has put me on the right path. May just ask our main dev to write the code above into a little plugin so we can see this in the backend.