# SQL to get customer email and size attribute (max count) of orders

Tags: orders, sql, query

We sell fashion. I was reading [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10648/sql-to-get-customer-emails-by-attribute-set-of-products-bought). Now how do I get a list of all customers who bought a size S shirts? (filter on size S).

Size is the attribute to define the simple product from configurable. In addition there may me weird cases where a customer ordered both 43 and 44 size, bit 44 size more often, so this is why we are suggesting to using a max to identify a customers favorite size

**Question:** How can we identify a customers favorite size using a query?

Help appreciated